# Determine number of variables and automatically bind_param with correct number of variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, prepared-statement

At the bottom I have a function that takes an array of MySQL queries and prepares statements automatically. So I can setup an array like the following:

```
$queryTest = array(
    array(
        'query' => 'SELECT * FROM tools WHERE RFID_tag = ? AND editedByID = ?',
        'paramTypes' => 'si',
        'params' => array('EXAMPLE_RFID_TAG', 1001)
    ),
    array(
        'query' => 'SELECT * FROM tool_categories WHERE categoryID = ?',
        'paramTypes' => 'i',
        'params' => array(1)
    )
);
```

Then call `$resultArray = db_multi_query($queryTest);` and you can handle it however you see fit after that.

**My question is**: Is there any better way to determine the number of statement variables I have in my array to automatically populate bind_param variables instead of doing it by checking the number of variables with `if(count($query['params']) == 5){` and then manaully adding more variables to bind_param? I want it to automatically populate bind_param with the variables so I can shorten this function and make it so that I'm not limited to the number of `if(count($query['params']) == int){` I setup in the function.

```
function db_multi_query(array $queries){
    global $MySQLi;
    $resultArray = array();
    foreach($queries as $query){
        $MySQLquery = $MySQLi->prepare($query['query']);
        if(count($query['params']) == 1){
            $MySQLquery->bind_param($query['paramTypes'], $query['params'][0]);
        }
        if(count($query['params']) == 2){
            $MySQLquery->bind_param($query['paramTypes'], $query['params'][0], $query['params'][1]);
        }
        if(count($query['params']) == 3){
            $MySQLquery->bind_param($query['paramTypes'], $query['params'][0], $query['params'][1], $query['params'][2]);
        }
        if(count($query['params']) == 4){
            $MySQLquery->bind_param($query['paramTypes'], $query['params'][0], $query['params'][1], $query['params'][2], $query['params'][3]);
        }
        if(count($query['params']) == 5){
            $MySQLquery->bind_param($query['paramTypes'], $query['params'][0], $query['params'][1], $query['params'][2], $query['params'][3], $query['params'][4]);
        }
        $MySQLquery->execute();
        $resultArray[] = $MySQLquery->get_result();
    }
    return $resultArray;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If this is MySQLi, then `bind_param()` will take multiple arguments via the splat operator: `$MySQLquery->bind_param($query['paramTypes'], ...$query['params']);`

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the reply. It is MySQLi. I understand I can give it multiple vars; my problem is the way I'm passing these variables to it and the efficiency of the way I'm doing so by checking the number of elements in an array.

Comment: PHP 5.6 introduced [argument packing/unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) aka the splat operator

Comment: @MarkBaker I may be overlooking something, but that still doesn't solve my problem. I can't pass arrays to bind_param. And if I'm supposed to be able to, it's just not letting me. When I try to pass $query['params'] directly to bind_param I get the error: `mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables`

Comment: If you use the splat operator, you're not passing `$query['params']` directly: with `...$query['params']`, you're unpacking `$query['params']` to pass the individual elements of the array

Comment: For PHP prior to 5.6 you can use `call_user_func_array([$MySQLquery, 'bind_param' ], array_merge([ $query['paramTypes'] ], $query['params']))`.

Comment: @MarkBaker My mistake, I missed what you were trying to say there. I didn't even know that was a thing! Thank you ever so much Mark! If you submit that as an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Array Unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list), aka the "splat" operator (and officially known as "Variadics") introduced in PHP 5.6.0, you can unpack the "params" array into your `bind_param()` call, so replacing

```
if(count($query['params']) == 1){
    $MySQLquery->bind_param($query['paramTypes'], $query['params'][0]);
}
if(count($query['params']) == 2){
    $MySQLquery->bind_param($query['paramTypes'], $query['params'][0], $query['params'][1]);
}
if(count($query['params']) == 3){
    $MySQLquery->bind_param($query['paramTypes'], $query['params'][0], $query['params'][1], $query['params'][2]);
}
if(count($query['params']) == 4){
    $MySQLquery->bind_param($query['paramTypes'], $query['params'][0], $query['params'][1], $query['params'][2], $query['params'][3]);
}
if(count($query['params']) == 5){
    $MySQLquery->bind_param($query['paramTypes'], $query['params'][0], $query['params'][1], $query['params'][2], $query['params'][3], $query['params'][4]);
}
```

with

```
if(count($query['params']) > 1) {
    $MySQLquery->bind_param($query['paramTypes'], ...$query['params']);
}
```

and then it doesn't matter how many parameters you're passing through, as long as the number tallies up with your `$query['paramTypes']`

Comment: Thanks Mark! I really appreciate your assistance with this!